# How to add Prerequisite folders in installshield?

Tags: windows-installer, installshield

We are using installShield to create setup.exe and msi files in Vs 2012. I have one prerequisite (dfcWinSuiteSetup.exe) which i need to install first. To install that, i create one prerequisite file(.prq) and specified that 3rd party exe path, but that exe has some dependencies on other files(some jar files). Now, when i build the solution and run the generated setup.exe it failed, as dependent jars are not part of setup.exe.
Can anybody tell me how i can include dependent jar in my setup.exe ?
My prq file is.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SetupPrereq>
    <conditions>
        <condition Type="16" Comparison="2" Path="[WindowsFolder]\Documentum" FileName="dctm.jar" ReturnValue=""></condition>
    </conditions>
    <files>
        <file LocalFile="&lt;ISProductFolder&gt;\SetupPreRequisites\Redistributables\dfcWinSuiteSetup.exe" URL="" FileSize="0,0"></file>
    </files>
    <execute file="dfcWinSuiteSetup.exe" cmdline="" cmdlinesilent=""></execute>
    <properties Id="{0278E528-E72C-439F-AE2A-BEFCB27EA9A3}" Description="This prerequisite installs the DFC for window setup" AltPrqURL=""></properties>
    <behavior Reboot="2"></behavior>
</SetupPrereq>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add multiple files inside the `<files>` element in your .prq file, exactly the same way you added the first one.

All the files listed in `<files>` will be embedded in the same folder (It will be something like : `ISSetupPrerequisites\{SOME-GUID-...}`)

Then, the `<execute file="..."/>` let the installer know which file has to be executed for your prerequisite.

Your .prq file should look like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SetupPrereq>
    <conditions>
        <condition Type="16" Comparison="2" Path="[WindowsFolder]\Documentum" FileName="dctm.jar" ReturnValue=""></condition>
    </conditions>
    <files>
        <file LocalFile="&lt;ISProductFolder&gt;\SetupPreRequisites\Redistributables\dfcWinSuiteSetup.exe" URL="" FileSize="0,0"></file>
        <!-- add your other files here -->
        <file LocalFile="PATH/TO/YOUR/JAR/FILE" URL="" [...] />
    </files>
    <execute file="dfcWinSuiteSetup.exe" cmdline="" cmdlinesilent=""></execute>
    <properties Id="{0278E528-E72C-439F-AE2A-BEFCB27EA9A3}" Description="This prerequisite installs the DFC for window setup" AltPrqURL=""></properties>
    <behavior Reboot="2"></behavior>
</SetupPrereq>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes..Superb..i waste my entire one day and concluded that its not possible in limited edition, but you just proved me wrong. Thanks a lot.